# Install "Utils Plugin" into the cakephp 3.x for image uploading

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to upload the image using `Utils Plugin` in cakephp 3. x,

We have not able to install this `Utils plugin` into cakephp 3.x.

I referred this link:

> https://github.com/cakemanager/cakephp-utils http://cakemanager.org/docs/utils/1.0/behaviors/uploadable/

Using this command in terminal `requires cakemanager/cakephp-utils: dev-master.`

I got an error 'The requested package c`akemanager/cakephp-Otis` 1.0 could not be found'

How to install the `Utils Plugin` into the cakephp 3. x ?

Anyone please help!

Thank You.

Comment: "_cakemanager/cakephp-Otis_", really? That's the CLI output? And what's up with this trailing dot in your composer command? And you're also sure about "_requires_", with `s`?

Comment: @ndm hi, I tried require "cakemanager/cakephp-utils:1.0.x-dev" got same error "- The requested package cakemanager/cakephp-utils could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name." .How to resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: You can install the plug into the cakephp 'require cakemanager/cakephp-utils:dev-master'
        (or)
    Put into    "require": {
        "cakemanager/cakephp-utils": "dev-master"
        }, 
Composer.json file and then Update the composer 'php composer.phar update' run the code in terminal

Step 2: Add the following line to your application's config/bootstrap.php file:

```
Plugin::load('Utils')
```

Step 3: Add the code into the Model file:

```
$this->addBehavior('Utils.Uploadable', [
 'avatar' => [                                                    //field_name of form input
        'field' => 'id',                                          //Any field from form (id=5)
        'path' => '{ROOT}{DS}{WEBROOT}{DS}uploads{DS}',           // Set path to webroot
        'fileName' => '{field}.{extension}'                       // File name with extension
        ],
     ]
]);
```

This is the example path "webroot/uploads/5.png" how the file will be save.

For more explanation please read this http://cakemanager.org/docs/utils/1.0/behaviors/uploadable/

Thank You.